# Is it safe to throw a fault exception from IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to check if it's safe to throw a fault exception in AfterReceiveRequest. I am using a Custom Message Inspector to check for security headers. If the security check fails I throw the exception.

On the surface this appears to work and the fault is returned to the client.

Of course this exception means the target service method is never called and neither is IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply.

Is it is safe to interrupt the WCF stack at this point?

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft itself it is a valid scenario:

[Patterns and practices](https://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Implement%20AfterReceiveRequest%20Method%20to%20Validate%20Inbound%20Messages%20on%20the%20Service)

Comment: This is now on page 303 of the PDF that can be downloaded by clicking the purple button on the top. The .pdf is the binary file in /2/ subfolder of the archive.